# jquery width method in td of table will get different length between IE and chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found  when I use  various explorer  to test $(xxx).width() in the td of table will be going to lead me to the  different width,so could anyone give me a perfect solution to get the same width or same  with chrome.VRPMain is the telerik grid.

```
$("#VRPMain>table>tbody>tr:first-child>td").each(function (i, item) {
                tempArr.push(Math.floor($(item).width()));
});
```